# Need help in running behaviour cloning

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run udacity behaviour cloning project but am unable to execute it.

The model is-

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dropout(args.keep_prob))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()
```

To run-
    python drive.py model.h5

On running, I am getting this-

> ```
>   File "model.py", line 34, in <lambda>
>     model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
> SystemError: unknown opcode
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has changed, your code will work fine upto Python 3.5.

Try,

```
model.add(x = lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
```